# Binomial Expansion, finding specific coefficient

Tags: binomial-coefficients, combinations, binomial-theorem

What is the coefficient on the $x^{135}$ term in the expansion of $\left(2+x^3\right)^{100}$?

I solved a similar question, but my method isn't working when the second term in the expansion is raised to a power other than 1.

Comment: What is the coefficient of the $a^{55}b^{45}$ term in the expansion of $(a+b)^{100}$?  What is the coefficient of the $b^{45}$ term in the expansion then of $(2+b)^{100}$?  What then is the coefficient of the $(x^{3})^{45}$ term in the expansion of $(2+x^3)^{100}$?  Of the $x^{135}$ term?

Answer (score 2):

The binomial theorem tells us that 
$$(a + b)^n =  \sum_{k = 1}^n  {{n}\choose{k}} a^kb^{n-k}.$$

Here $a = 2$ and $b = x^3$. Solve for what $k$ needs to be for the $x^{135}$ term, and then ${{n}\choose{k}} a^k$ will be your coefficient! Let me know if you need any more help!

Comment: Thank you for your response! So, I think that the k I am looking for would be 132, because x raised to 135-132 is x^3. Am I correct?

Comment: No, here you need $45$ because $(x^3)^{45} = x^{135}$ when you have an exponent to an exponent, you multiply. What you were thinking of is the fact that $x^3x^{132} = x^{135}$, but that's not what's happening here.